# KStream left join doesn't produce record on left side null

Tags: spring, kotlin, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have the following left join to sink code, which should have created a record when `healthStream` got a message, but it's only producing a record when both streams have a message.

```
val cncStream = streamsBuilder.stream(config.cncManagerTopic,
    Consumed.with<String, AgentMessage>(Serdes.String(), AgentMessageSerde()))

val healthStream = streamsBuilder.stream(config.healthTopic,
    Consumed.with<String, AgentMessage>(Serdes.String(), AgentMessageSerde()))


healthStream.leftJoin(cncStream,
    { healthMsg, logsMessage -> Agent(
        healthMsg.generateKey(), healthMsg.context.customerId, healthMsg.context.agentId, healthMsg.healthMsg.status.toString(),
        healthMsg.healthMsg.message, LocalDateTime.now(), healthMsg.healthMsg.metrics,
        LogStatus((logsMessage?.logsUploadedMsg?.ok == true), logsMessage?.logsUploadedMsg?.error.orEmpty(), logsMessage?.logsUploadedMsg?.path.orEmpty()) )
    },
    JoinWindows.ofTimeDifferenceWithNoGrace(Duration.ofMinutes(5)),
    StreamJoined.`as`(KafkaAgentsConfiguration.GetStoreName(config.agentsTopic)))
    .to(config.agentsTopic, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), AgentSerde()))
```

Is it a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

`JoinWindow` duration doesn't change the results.